# Galaxy Note 4 CSS Pixels

Tags: css, samsung-mobile

Does anyone know what the CSS pixel resolution for the Galaxy Note 4 is?  I can't seem to find this or the device pixel ratio anywhere.

A couple places I've looked that I thought would have this information but don't:

```
http://viewportsizes.com/
http://www.devicepixelratio.com/
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Note_4
http://www.samsung.com/global/microsite/galaxynote4/note4_specs.html
```

Comment: Are you specifically asking about the hw pixel to css pixel ratio in the browser? Because the hw resolution is 515 ppi according to [a quick Google](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_note_4-6434.php).

Comment: I'm not sure what hw resolution is but I don't think we are talking about the same thing. Here is an article that explains what CSS pixels are. http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this its 640x360 with a DPR of 4.

http://www.canbike.org/CSSpixels/

Answer (score 2):

I think it is 360x640 with a density of 4.